# OpenCV Contours exact Width and Length

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am trying to find out the exact length and width of the contours. Basically i am trying to find out the scratches and their exact length. Refer to the image below:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how I can find the exact thickness of these cracks. I have tried the boundingrect() function to retrieve the width and height but that does not fulfill the purpose since its not accurate to the line of the scratches. I was thinking if i can find the scratch implementation of draw contours because drawcontours() is able to draw on them accurately.
Anyone??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a solution to get exactly what you want out of the box, but since these scratches are just two lines really close to each other, you can probably get pretty close to what you need by using the arc length feature of contours:

```
perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
length = perimeter / 2;
```

There are other features and properties of contours you can use to try and calculate the exact length yourself. Properties like Extreme Points and Pixel Points come to mind. You can find more info on these from the [documentation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_properties/py_contour_properties.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first you can use skeletonize to thining your scratch into a single line, then use the cv2.arclength to calculate the length of the line.